# Open server создание страниц

Tags: php, html

Впервые делаю сайт на локальном сервере, так как в некоторых случаях мне нужно написать что-то на php. В видео-уроках показано, что создавать сайт нужно в папке "domains" под индексом `.php` (Я использую OpenServer) Как я понял, в файле под индексом `php` можно писать html код, а когда нужно что-то написать на php открывать тег `<?php` Так вот, я до конца не понимаю, если я хочу сделать сайт у которого много страниц - всегда нужно создавать файл с индексом именно php и писать свой html код? Все страницы будут с этим индексом (кроме css, js), правильно ли это будет? Или некоторые страницы можно писать под индексом `html`?

Comment: если сайт пишете на php, то у разметки будет расширение php в противном случае php не заработает(с разметкой будет все норм). Юзаните хоть один фреймверк php, и загляните ему "под капот" - увидите как все устроено.

Comment: Спасибо, а если я на php пишу коротенький код, который даёт возможность загружать на все страницы сайта, меню, что бы на каждой странице меню не делать, то ничего что я из-за короткого кода php пишу html разметку страницы с индексом php?)

Comment: если индекс - это расширение файла, то ничего )

Comment: Да, расширение файла, благодарю за ответ )